# knitr: where is the output from example(help=knitr)?

Tags: r, knitr

With a chunk like the following, why is the output from the example() call not appearing in the output for me?  Have I missed something obvious?

````
```{r}
require(knitr)
2+2
help(package='knitr')
```
````

I see "## 4" in the output, but not the help() output.

Thanks, Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`help(package='knitr')` returns an object of the class `packageInfo`, and `print.packageInfo()` shows the formatted version of this object in a temp *file* via `file.show()`, which does not write anything to `stdout()`, so there is no way to capture the output.

You can write the help info into `stdout` manually using `format()` + `cat()`:

```
cat(format(help(package='knitr')), sep = '\n')
```